# Multi-Criteria Search via three comboxes in vb.net with sql back end

Tags: sql, vb.net, search, datagridview, combobox

I am currently working in VB.net with an sql back end server. I have a windows form application with a datagridview and 3 combo boxes that have data from three different columns in the datagridview. So far I have used IF statements for multi-criteria searches. This method has proven to be a long and inefficient way to write this code. It is literally a long run of IF statements saying if combobox1.selectedindex does not equal 1 and combobox 2 and 3 are still on the -1 index then search with just the first combo box. Then I write the code for every single possibility of the comboboxes being filled out. Whether it is 2 or all of them, or just one of them. I am wondering if there is a solid tutorial or a way to loop through these comboboxes to make this code quick and simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you started. It defines a list of combo boxes which you want to check and then determines which ones have a `SelectedIndex <> -1`. If it doesn't then the value is recorded.

```
' Build a list of values based on combo boxes with a selected index.
Dim values As New List(Of String)

' Build an array of combo boxes we want to process.
For Each cb As ComboBox In New ComboBox() {comboBox1, comboBox2, comboBox3}
    ' Check if the current combo box has an index selected.
    If cb.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        ' It does - record its value.
        values.Add(cb.Text)
    End If
Next

' Do something with the values.
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(", ", values.ToArray))

' For example, build a where clause.
' If you do this, be sure to sanitize the values.
MessageBox.Show("WHERE 0=1 " & String.Join(" OR Field=", values.ToArray))
```